# Javascript issue with this._super() function

Tags: javascript

I have the following javascript

```
var helloworld == cc.layer.extend({
    ctor : function() { this._super(); }
    init : function() { this._super();  ........}
    onmix : function() { this._super(); this.layer.addChild(); }
});
```

The error I am getting is this doesn't know `this._super()` at `onmix` function but everywhere else `this._super()` is fine.    If I don't put `this._super()` inside `onmix` then it won't know `this.layer` object. So how should I fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: What library are you using, that gives objects a `_super()` function?  That's not built into vanilla JS.

Answer (score 0):

```
var helloworld == <...>
```

Is not valid JS syntax.  I think you mean just '=' instead.